# SASS - How to synchronise style.scss with style.css file?

Tags: sass, compilation

I'm using SASS, writing in style.scss compiling to (style.css & style.map.css), but how to convert style.css file to completely normal style.css file?

The compiled style.css file looks like this

```css
div{
    margin: 0 auto;}
    p {
      text-align: center;}
```

How to convert it into normal.css?

Comment: We need more information. If you're successfully compiling your SCSS into CSS, style.css should already be a "normal" CSS file. Can you explain more about what you're trying to achieve, and why?

Comment: This is already a normal CSS file.

Comment: Yes, but how to make parentheses on a new line, and the tags also on a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [default output style](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style) for Sass is normally `nested`, which is the style/formatting you see in your `style.css` file.

Possible options are:

- `nested`
- `expanded`
- `compressed`
- `compact`

If you change the output to `expanded` before compiling your file, you will probably get the style you want.

```
sass --watch scss:css --style expanded
```

Will produce this:

```
div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

PS. If you are using somtehing like Gulp, the task could be set up like this:

```
.pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for, many Thanks. Just one more question - the command creates style.css file and style.css.map file - how the program knows where to put them and how to name them?

Comment: If you are using the command line, the `.map` file will always be in the same folder and with the same name, as far as I know.

Comment: PS. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the grey checkmark on the left side of my answer :)